# C# and C++ Library

Tags: c#, c++, c, interop, cross-compiling

- I was wondering if I can use [a library](http://www.cimne.com/flood/) -**written in C++**- in **C#**
- The problem is that library has its own structures and classes.. 
  Will I be able to use it in C#?

Thanks

**EDIT**
 This library is open source..
 so if my requirements needs something special in C++ code, I will be able do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly use C++ classes in managed code.  The chief problems are not being able to use the same memory allocator as used by the C++ code and not being able to invoke the constructor and destructor easily.  A Microsoft employee posted [a blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2008/12/08/inheriting-from-a-native-c-class-in-c.aspx) to show that it is not impossible.  I would not recommend doing this.

COM is a solution but that invariably requires a fairly big rewrite and good COM programming skillz.  A [managed class wrapper](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/quickcppcli.aspx#A8) in the C++/CLI language is usually the best solution.  You could take a peek at the [SWIG tool](http://www.swig.org/) to consider auto-generating those wrapper classes.  Beware however that this tool can easily create more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways, both using an Adapter (which maps C++ classes to .NET classes):

- C++/CLI
- COM

The former avoids going via COM, and much of the C++ code might be able to be just compiled with the correct switches.

Additional: In theory P/Invoke might be possible, but all the C++ semantics would be lost, you would need to handle C++ object lifetime manually (and instance references as `IntPtr`). Plus of course you would need to call the mangled names...

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to write a managed wrapper in C++/CLI. I prefer that instead of using P/Invoke.